# error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/E-wave112/myadmissionportalsite2.git'

Tags: python, django, git

I am trying to push my  django files and folders to my git repository through git on the command line

the steps i took to push my files are:

git init

git add --all

git commit -m "my message"

git remote add origin (remote url)

and finally

git push -u origin master

and i then get this error:

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/E-wave112/myadmissionportalsite2.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

itried possible solutions but i got nothing

how can i fix this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+remote+contains+work+that+you+do

Answer (score 6):

fixed already !

all i needed was this single ommand

```
git push origin master --force
```